# Chaincode Argument Error while working with minifab implementation

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, blockchain, hyperledger-chaincode, minifab

I am trying to run fabric network locally using minifab tutorial. While making my first transaction, I am encountering following error.

Here is my command

```
minifab invoke -p '"invoke","a","b","4"'
```

Error Details

```
non-zero return code
  Error: chaincode argument error: invalid character 'i' looking for beginning of value
  Usage:
    peer chaincode invoke [flags]
```

Answer (score 0):

windows version of minifab requires below command(with backslashes)

```
minifab invoke -p \"invoke\",\"a\",\"b\",\"4\"
```

This will solve the problem.